# Visual Studio 2013 - JSLint.NET installed but not showing in tools?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, jslint, visual-studio-extensions

I am new to VS.
Went to Extensions and installed JSLint.NET, it is also enabled.
But I get no item under Tools to configure or use it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JSLint.NET is configured on per project basis.  Right click on your project and you should see a menu choice for JSLint.NET Project Settings.

You can see an example of this on the Visual Studio gallery page for the extension.

[JSLint.NET Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ede12aa8-0f80-4e6f-b15c-7a8b3499370e?SRC=VSIDE)