# Visual Studio 2013 - JSLint.NET install on web project does not show the expected Jslint menu options

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging, jslint

I have a web application and have installed jsLint.NET on this project but the JSLint menu does not show up at all. What do I need to do, in addition, to get the menu showing up when I right click my project folders and files please? I am on a Visual Studio 2013 pro edition on a windows 7 machine.

PS. This question has not been answered as the response provided at the link does not make sense in my case.

**[Visual Studio 2013 - JSLint.NET installed but not showing in tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21802536/visual-studio-2013-jslint-net-installed-but-not-showing-in-tools)**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2013 - JSLint.NET installed but not showing in tools?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21802536/visual-studio-2013-jslint-net-installed-but-not-showing-in-tools)

Comment: i don't understand what you mean'

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed on a project, that sounds like the [JSLint.NET for MSBuild](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JSLintNet.MSBuild/) NuGet package. This package wires up targets that run JSLint every time the project is built (locally or on a build server), so there is no menu or other IDE integration - it just runs automatically.

To edit the options for your project, there are a couple of options.

- The NuGet package includes a tool for editing settings. Create a blank JSLintNet.json file in the root of the project folder and drag it onto JSLintNet.Console.exe. This is found in the tools folder wherever the NuGet package is installed (for example, \packages\JSLintNet.MSBuild.1.7.0\tools).
- Install the [JSLint.NET for Visual Studio](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ede12aa8-0f80-4e6f-b15c-7a8b3499370e?SRC=VSIDE) extension which adds menus and settings editor integration. The NuGet package and Visual Studio extension can live side by side quite happily.